# Wait for a child process to finish before starting new child process

Tags: bash, shell, wait, gnome-terminal

I have to process ten very big files. Each file takes about two days to process by `my_profiler`. I can parallelize the work so that `my_profiler` runs on each file separately, hence using all of my system's cores. My approach at parallelizing the work is to run three processes in three different terminals at the time. I can't process more than four files at once, or my system starts getting unresponsive (hangs up).

My goal is to write a shell script which processes the ten files in batches of size three. Once processing of one file finishes, the terminal should be closed and processing of a new file should start in another terminal. As a terminal I want to use `gnome-terminal`.

Currently I am stuck with the following script, which runs all processes in parallel:

```sh
for j in $jobs
do
    gnome-terminal -- bash -c "my_profiler $j"
done
```

How I can wait until a shell script running in a instance of `gnome-terminal` finishes?

My first thought was that I might need to send a signal form the old terminals once their job is finished.

Comment: Not running separate commands in separate terminals would be an excellent start.

Comment: @tripleee This is not my choice this is my need. I mentioned that in first few lines.

Comment: You should really separate your workload management from your display presentation. Maybe run the individual tasks in `tmux` and connect each terminal to the session you want it to display or something like that.

Comment: @tripleee Can I do that using wait command if the process state changes for earlier opened terminals, I can send a signal to bash script. How is that possible?

Comment: It is absolutely not clear why every process must run in a separate terminal

Comment: @Leon To parallelise my computation, so that on every core I run separate process.

Comment: @Đēēpak You don't need multiple terminals for that. Multiple processes can be executed in the same shell.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269146/wait-until-gnome-terminal-ends/538607

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not quite sure why you have to start a new `gnome-terminal` for each job. But you could use `xargs` in combination with `-P` <sup>[1]</sup>. Running three `my_profiler` in parallel at the same time:

```sh
echo "${jobs}" | xargs -P3 -I{} gnome-terminal --wait -e 'bash -c "my_profiler {}"'
```

Important here is to start `gnome-terminal` with `--wait` otherwise the terminal demonizes itself which will have the effect that `xargs` starts the next process. `--wait` was introduced with [`gnome-terminal` 3.27.1](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/commit/42f9f7978e3d103af7a5c9eb2c8f0e8d40e0647c).

The `-I{}` option to `xargs` defines a placeholder (`{}`) which `xargs` will replace with a filename before running the command <sup>[2]</sup>. In the example above, `xargs` scans the command string (`gnome-terminal --wait -e 'bash -c "my_profiler {}"'`) for `{}` and replaces the found instances with the first file coming from stdin (`echo "${jobs}" | ...`). The resulting string it then executes. `xargs` will do this three times (`-P3`), before it starts waiting for at least one process to finish. If this happens, `xargs` will start the next process.

---

[1]: from `man xargs`

> `-P max-procs`, `--max-procs=max-procs`
>
> Run  up  to max-procs processes at a time; the default is 1. If `max-procs` is 0, `xargs` will run as many processes as possible at a time. Use the `-n` option or the `-L` option with `-P`; otherwise chances are that only one exec will be done. While `xargs` is  running, you can send its process a `SIGUSR1` signal to increase the number of commands to run simultaneously, or a `SIGUSR2` to decrease the number. You cannot increase it above an implementation-defined limit (which is shown with `--show-limits`). You cannot decrease it below 1. `xargs` never terminates its commands; when asked to decrease, it merely waits for more than one existing command to terminate before starting another.
>
> **Please note** that it is up to the called processes to properly manage parallel access to shared resources. For example, if more than one of them tries to print to stdout, the ouptut will be produced in an indeterminate order (and very likely mixed up) unless the processes collaborate in some way to prevent this. Using some kind of locking scheme is one way to prevent such problems. In general, using a locking scheme will help ensure correct output but reduce performance. If you don't want to tolerate the performance difference, simply arrange for each process to produce a separate output file (or otherwise use separate resources).

[2]: from `man xargs`

> `-I replace-str`
>
> Replace occurrences of `replace-str` in the initial-arguments with names  read from standard input. Also, unquoted blanks do not terminate input items; instead the separator is the newline character. Implies `-x` and `-L 1`.

Comment: This is working but these processess are working in background. How can I see them in gnome-terminals. I want to see the progress in these terminals.

Comment: well then start `gnome-terminal` with xargs, will update my answer. stay tuned.

Comment: Thanks @Ente. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for your edit to question and answer. But please help me understand the flags you used in your code. I saw the man page of xargs but couldn't understand it. Please help me with {} parameter that you have used.

Comment: @Đēēpak you are welcome. See my latest, update. If you are satisfied with the answer, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this right...

I think you could use `wait $job` in order for the job to complete.

Here's an example.
Following script will start max. 3 jobs in parallel, in background.
Once one of these 3 jobs will end, it will start another one.

```
#!/bin/bash

THREADS='3';
FILES=$(find source_dir_path -type f -name "your files*")

for file in ${FILES}
do
 NUMPROC=$(ps -ef |grep -i [y]our_process_name| wc -l |tr -d ' ')
 while (( $NUMPROC >= 3))
 do
  sleep 60
  NUMPROC=$(ps -ef |grep -i [y]our_process_name| wc -l |tr -d ' ')
 done
 echo "Starting: " $file;
 #your file processing command below, I assume this would be:
 my_profiler $file &
done

for job in `jobs -p`
do
 wait $job
done
```

Answer (score 1):

> Each file takes about 2 days to process

Running them in a graphical window is the most expensive operation there is. Flushing the terminal window can be expensive, if your process outputs lot of stdout (like `cp -vr /bigfolder /anotherfolder`) you will see performance difference. Also, running an X application with background job makes it dependent on X server - if your X server crashes, you loose your work. That all is unrelated work to what you are trying to do.

For single run workloads (run&forget), I would go with `xargs -Pjobs`. I would add some `ionice nice` to make the system usable white the process is running. The processes stdout output could be discarded, interleaved with some prefix added ex. with `| sed 's/^/'"${job}: "'/'`, saved to a file. Or better, `| logger` redirected to system logger.

If it would be a one-time job, I would open a `tmux` or `screen` session, type:

```
printf "%s\n" $jobs | ionice nice xargs -t -P$(nproc) sh -c 'my_profiler "$1"' --
```

and discard the `tmux` or `screen` session for later use. Set an alarm on my phone in 3 days and check it in 3 days later.

The `ionice nice` will make your system somehow usable while the processes are processing. The `-P$(nproc)` will limit the processes to the number of cores. If the `my_profiler` is highly I/O dependent and you don't care about the system performance while running the jobs, It's sometimes advisable to run more jobs then cores, as they will block on I/O anyway.

You could add `| logger -p local0.info --id=$$` to the end after `xargs` or inside child `sh` shell inside `xargs`, so that it will redirect the output to system log using `local0.info` priority and id of the PID of the current shell.

A way better in my opinion option is to create a systemd service file. Create such `my_profiles@.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run my_profiler for %i
[Service]
# full path to my_profiler
ExecStart=/usr/bin/my_profiler %i
CPUSchedulingPolicy=batch
Nice=19
IOSchedulingClass=best-effort
```

Add the service to search path with `systemd link my_profiler@.service` or create that as a dropin service file inside `/var/run/systemd/system`. Then start running it with `printf "%s\n" $jobs | xargs -I{} -t systemctl start ./my_profiler@{}.service`.

That way I could get all the logs I need from `journalctl -u my_profiler@job.service` and logs will never fill 100% of my disc space, because `journalctl` checks that.  Errors will be easily reported and inspected with `systemd list-failed` or `systemd status my_profiler@job.service`.

Comment: @skazichris  Can you please pinpoint on which distros? That would be strange. The [xargs sources from findutils](https://github.com/Distrotech/findutils/blob/distrotech-findutils-4.5.10/xargs/xargs.c#L591) make it impossible to compile without `-P` option and the option was introduced 24(!) years ago. If you have `xargs` implementation without `-P` option, I believe it's not from `findutils`, which would be strange. I see that even [macos xargs](https://ss64.com/osx/xargs.html) has `-P`.

Comment: Well... have you checked eg AIX 6.1 or 7.1? 
I have to use workarounds each time I want to use parallel processing.
Reference:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/231578/how-to-have-a-process-queue-in-aix-like-xargs-with-max-procs

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach, because counting the processes based on a substring in the process table might be problematic. Especially if you start subprocesses in your script the count can be unreliable.
You also wrote, that the processes run for 2 days, so you might have the problem at times, that you need to restart from the prefious point.

You could do that in just a bit more complicated way. You need one script that starts your processes and watches them if they still look healty (the process did not crash --> otherwise it restarts them). This requires an init script, the script which fills the process queue and a small modification of your profiler script.

## Script 1: initialize the process

Create a job directory with one file per job in order to track the progress automatically. If all jobs can be processed without problems, it will be deleted automatically later.

```
#!/bin/bash
tmpdir=/tmp/
jobdir=${tmpdir}/jobs
num_jobs=3
mkdir -p ${jobdir}

i=1
for file in $jobs ; do
    ((i++))
    echo "${file}" > ${jobdir}/${i}.open
done
```

## Script 2: starting the actual processes

```
#!/bin/bash
jobdir=${tmpdir}/jobs
num_jobs=3

function fill_process_queue() {
    # arg1: num_jobs
    # arg2: jobdir
    # arg3...: open jobs
    num_jobs=$1
    jobdir=$2
    shift 2
    while [[ $(ls ${jobdir}/*.running.* | wc -l) -lt ${num_jobs} -a $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
        job_file=$1
        shift 1
        gnome-terminal -- bash -c "my_profiler $(cat ${jobdir}/${job_file}) ${jobdir}/${job_file}"
        # now give the called job some time to
        # mark it's territory (rename the job file)
        sleep 5s
    done
}

while [[ -z $(ls ${jobdir}) ]] ; do
    # still files present, so first check if
    # all started processes are still running
    for started_job in $(ls ${jobdir}/*.running.* 2>/dev/null) ; do
        # check if the running processes are still alive
        pid= "{started_job//[0-9]\.running\.}"
        jobid= "{started_job//\.running\.[0-9]*}"
        if ! kill -0 ${pid} 2> /dev/null ; then
            # process is not running anymore
            # don't worry kill -0 doesn't harm your
            # process
            mv ${jobdir}/${started_job} ${jobdir}/${jobid}
        fi
    done
    fill_process_queue ${num_jobs} ${jobdir} ${jobdir}/*.open
    sleep 30s
done
# if the directory is empty, it will be removed automatically by rmdir, if non-empty, it remains
rmdir ${jobdir}
```

## Changes of the profiler script

The profiler script needs to rename the job file, so it includes the pid of the profiler script at the start of the script and needs to delete the file, once it is sucessfully finished. The file name is passed as extra argument after the job argument (so it should be argument 2).
These changes look like:

```
# at the very beginning of your script
process_file=${2//\.open/}.running.$$
mv $2 ${process_file}

# at the very end of your script, if everything went fine
rm ${process_file}
```